# JPA, Composite Key consisted of foreign key and table column members

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

Greetings to the community,

I am struggling all day to find a solution to the issue below.

The scenario is the following, I have a table

`---TABLE_ONE---
    INT ID
    VARCHAR NAME
    PRIMARY_KEY (ID)`

and my other table consisted of three columns which consist together a composite key

`---TABLE_TWO---
  INT TABLE_ONE_ID (FK -> TABLE_ONE.ID)
  VARCHAR NAME 
  VARCHAR EMAIL 
  PRIMARY_KEY(TABLE_ONE_ID, NAME, EMAIL)`

The relationship I want to achieve is that the `TABLE_ONE` entity will
have a list of objects from the `TABLE_TWO` (one-to-many relationship).

I tried to do this with as shown below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_ONE")
public class TableOne {

  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name="name")
  private String name
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "tableOne")
  private List<TableTwo> tableTwoList;
  //getters, setters, constructors        
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_TWO")
public class TableTwo {

  @EmbeddedId
  private TableTwoCompositeId tableTwoCompositeId;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_ONE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private TableOne tableOne;
  //getters, setters, constructors        
}


@Embeddable
public class TableTwoCompositeId {
    @Column(name = "TABLE_ONE_ID")
    public Integer provider;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    public String email;
    //getters, setters, constructors
}
```

However, I'm getting `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` and `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` when a TableOne object is retrieved from the database.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need several minor changes:

- `TableOne.id` needs an `@Id` annotation
- The type of `TableTwoCompositeId.provider` should match the type of `TableOne.id`
- `TableTwo.tableOne` needs a `@MapsId` annotation to indicate it maps `TableTwoCompositeId.provider`

Here is how the code should look:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_ONE")
public class TableOne {

  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name="name")
  private String name
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "tableOne")
  private List<TableTwo> tableTwoList;
  //getters, setters, constructors        
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_TWO")
public class TableTwo {

  @EmbeddedId
  private TableTwoCompositeId tableTwoCompositeId;
  @MapsId("provider") // maps provider attribute of embedded id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_ONE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private TableOne tableOne;
  //getters, setters, constructors        
}


@Embeddable
public class TableTwoCompositeId {
    @Column(name = "TABLE_ONE_ID")
    public int provider;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    public String email;
    //getters, setters, constructors
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did the changes you suggested but the List<TableTwo> tableTwoList is getting the value below

`Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException' exception.`

Comment: Something sounds a bit off. Maybe you can include the entire stack trace in the question.